# xslt fn:replace not working as expected

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

i'm trying to replace the string `location` to `tocation` so basically this is my code:

```
<div id="{fn:replace('location','l','t')}">
```

but instead of giving me `tocation` it gives me `t` ?!

Live Example: go to http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex1
In the second textarea put in this code and hit the button `Edit and Click Me`:

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <div>
    <xsl:value-of select="fn:replace('location','l','t')"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Still... do not use browsers :)

Comment: @empo what are my alternatives?

Comment: I'm using [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml) 9 for XSLT 2.0 and 6.5 for XSLT 1.0. I'm also using MSXSL for XSLT 1.0. I don't consider them _alternatives_; they are _must_ :)

Comment: @empo btw just curious. why do you ever need 1.0 if you have 2.0?

Comment: I use XSLT 2.0 myself when possible, that is, when I am completely free to choose the underlaying technology. In your case, as you are using a browser, I assume you need XSLT just to display HTML views of your XML. Therefore you are completely free (and it would be much easier for you) to simply install an XSLT processor and use it from the command line to generate your HTML through XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I can't repro the reported problem**.

When I perform this transformation using both Saxon 9.1.05 and XQSharp:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <div id="{replace('location','l','t')}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**on any XML document (not used), the result in both cases is the expected, correct one**:

```
<div xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="tocation"/>
```

**This means that you are using a non-compliant/buggy XSLT 2.0 processor**.

Contact the vendor and file a bug.

**In case you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor**, you will need to write a recursive named template to do simple generic replace (not using RegExes). There are a number of good examples of such in the "xslt" tag that can be found in answers to similar questions.

**The specific change you want to perform, however, can be done even more easily**:

```
<div id="{translate('location','l','t')}"/>
```

Comment: is there any difference if you use version `1.0` ?

Comment: @Pacerier: Then most probably you are using XSLT 1.0 -- `replace()` is only implemented in XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0 processors.

Comment: @Pacerier: I have updated my answer with two alternative XSLT 1.0 solutions.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev heys could you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288212/client-side-xslt-parsing-programs. i can't do any XSLT without solving that problem arg..

Comment: @Pacerier: I answered your question.