# Parsing XSLT offline on the client side

Tags: xslt

Are there any offline (without having to submit code through a webserver) parsers for XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*XSLT IDEs* (Interactive Development Environments):

- **[XSelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xselerator)** (the one I've been using for 6-7 years). Free, has a Debugger for MSXML, has intellisense for both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. In addition has some dynamic intellisense. The debugger has breakpoints, data breakpoints,visualizes temporary trees, variables, test conditions, current output, ..., etc.
- **[VS2008](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/default.mspx)** -- a good XML Editor + XSLT Debugger. Good static intellisence. Match patterns are statically checked. Breakpoints, data breakpoints, visualization of variables and the current output.
- **[oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)**
- **[XML-SPY](http://www.altova.com/products/xmlspy/xml_editor.html) (Altova)**
- **[Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/)**

*XPath tools*:

- **The [XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV-Zip-2008.zip)** -- A [**popular tool for learning XPath**](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html) by playing with XPath expressions. Free and open source. Allows any XPath expression to be evaluated against a given XML document and displayes the results hi-lighted in the xml document (if they are node(s)) or in a separate box (if the results are atomic values). Allows xsl:variable-s to be defined and then used in XPath expressions. Allows xsl:key-s to be defined and then referenced by key() functions within XPath expressions.

**EDIT**: The XPath Visualizer now has a **[new, safer home](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**, due to the kindness of Lars Huttar.

Comment: the XSelerator link is broken

Comment: btw http://www.xml.com/pub/r/1366 states XSelerator can only be used for up to 14 + 21 days for free.. is that true?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, since recently the XSelerator project disappeared from sourceforge.net. I contacted the author and he explained that they evicted XSelerator because only binaries are provided. I think he is now looking for a new site. Ask someone who has the zip file to give it to you.

Comment: @Pacerier: Ask the auther of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064024/xsl-xslt-calendar-with-xml-feed -- she (@Heather (user:761683) ) said that she found the XSelerator with Googling -- or perhaps ask @Flynn1179 (user:283505).

Answer (score 1):

I use JEdit with the XSLT plugin. It has a "three-way mode" which is awesome, since you see the input, the xslt and the output at the same time. It has some autocompletion capabilities too.

Comment: do i need to download the plugin at http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?XSLT or do i just have to install it from the IDE's plugin manager without having to downlaod any other additional things?

Comment: IIRC you can install it from the IDE's plugin manager, which also installs its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

[Kernow](http://kernowforsaxon.sourceforge.net/) gets you started with [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Kernow is cool. but does it comes with an Editor (code coloring and intelligence.. albeit limited) too?

Comment: That's what the product page refers to as "syntax highlighting" and "as-you-type syntax checking". Kernow is not a full-fledged IDE, but it is simple and effective, and definitly worth giving it a try.