# Copy portion of an XML with XSL without applying templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to apply a XSL template to a portion of the XML and copy the rest unmodified in the result XML.

For the time being I'm doing something that works.

```
<xsl:template match="yt:bold">
  <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="ancestor::ReportContent"> //I keep the ReportContent unchanged
            <xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                 <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <b>
              <xsl:apply-templates />
            </b>
       </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

But I'm doing this for each template... and I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this.

I tried to copy portion of the XML using this template:

```
<xsl:template match="ReportContent">
<xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:apply-templates select="???" /></xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

But I apply all the other templates when copying... and I don't want that.

So is there a more elegant way to do what I want to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
<xsl:template match="yt:bold[not(ancestor::ReportContent)]">
  <b>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </b>
</xsl:template>
```

Or perhaps

```
<xsl:template match="ReportContent">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

?

Comment: The second one was what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. I will have a closer look at the function xsl:copy-of

Comment: heys btw Dimitre Novatchev told me to contact you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288212/client-side-xslt-parsing-programs/6292747)  do you mind emailing a copy of XSelerator to me at Vaasdf@gmail.com

Comment: Well, he did say 'Perhaps'.. unfortunately I haven't used it myself, so I can't help you with this.